# Why was Polnareff able to see stands when he didn't have one?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

In Golden Wind, there are multiple episodes where Polnareff's stand Silver Chariot is separated from him, which causes all souls in a radius to swap bodies.

Polnareff ends up in the body of a turtle, and even though he no longer has a stand (it is operating on its own) he can still see stands.

His lack of having a stand is also the reason he was able to grab the arrow at the end of [episode 35 of Golden Wind](https://jojo.fandom.com/wiki/GW_Episode_35).

**Why can he still see stands if he no longer has one?**

Comment: I haven’t gotten to that part yet, so some speculation: 1) Are the other affected characters also able to see stands? This may affect the answer. 2) From what I read in the Wiki, Polnareff is transferred to the turtle stand user (who is apparently named Coco Jumbo, according to the Wiki). This is probably relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I have two explanations why this is the case:

## Although Silver Chariot has gone Berserk, it's still his Stand

First of all, although he can't control Silver Chariot Requiem anymore doesn't mean it's not his Stand anymore. In the flashback where Polnareff first found out about what happens when Silver Chariot has the Stand-Arrow, we can see that after taking the Arrow from Silver Chariot Requiem away again, the Stand transforms back into it's former normal self. So I'd say that even in the case of Polnareff not being able to control his Requiem-Stand anymore, he still *is* a Stand-User. Also, the reason why he was able to pick the Arrow up was because his Stand was already active and the effect of the Arrow (your Stand attacking you) still happens as we can see with Silver Chariot Requiem running towards him after picking up the Arrow.

## Polnareff took over the Turtle's Stand

The second case why he can still see Stands is because the Turtle (aka. Coco Jumbo) was a Stand-User and Polnareff's soul got transferred into the Turtle. At the end we also see that Coco Jumbo's Stand "Mr. President" is still active because we see Trish getting transferred inside the Turtle just like before the Silver Chariot Requiem incident. I'm guessing that Polnareff just took over the Turtle's Stand which is definitely plausible in certain cases.

**Part 6 Spoiler:**

> Obtaining someone else's Stand in addition to your own is possible in some special cases like we see with Emporio being able to use Weather Report in addition to Burning down the House at the end of Stone Ocean

So although it isn't explicitly stated in the anime/manga, Polnareff still certainly *is* a Stand-User.